# Restore previous wordpress site in Godaddy after enabling hosting service for its domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

I have a Wordpress site hosted somewhere, and a domain name registered at Godaddy.

Today I have enabled the Godaddy hosting service for the same domain. Suddenly, my website stopped working. A different coming soon page appeared.

I needed to access the previous website settings on Wordpress panel, then I decided to restore the hosting service defaults, but nothing happened.

My question: How can I restore website/DNS settings, being aware that I don't know my original hosting DNS/credentials? Did I lost my website?

Edit: I have FTP access and I can see the files still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in this topic, but since no one answered, I'll give it a shot.

The way I see it, when you enabled Godaddy hosting service on that same domain, the nameservers got overridden to point to Godaddy hosting. This is why you have "coming soon" page now.

So the solution should be:

1. Find the nameservers of the hosting company where the WordPress site is hosted. Usually, this information is public.
2. Next, on Godaddy, you should be able to edit the domain settings and replace the nameservers, so that they point to the one from step 1.

You can use this [article](http://hgusers.com/godaddy-domain-hostgator-hosting/) about pointing domain name from Godaddy To Hostgator for a guide on how to achieve this in more detail. Just replace Hostgator nameservers with yours (step 1).